# Difference between SEM AND ols+pca

Tags: least-squares, structural-equation-modeling, lavaan

Can someone explain me the difference between these approaches, if you want i can provide the results, but since they are quite extensive, i could attach on demand.
I'm working with the Theory of Planned Behavior, lets say

- a1,a2,a3,a4 are for construct A
- s1,s2,s3,s4 are for construct S
- p1,p2,p3,p4 are for construct P
  Then my model has two regressions:
  Int ~A + S + P
  Beh ~ P + Int

So far, so good... i can run this and perform some evaluations,
but then i was wondering using pca to reduce my a1,a2,...s1....p4, and extract 3 factors.
Lets call these, A_x, S_x and P_X
Then I could run a sem
Int ~A_x + S _x + P _x
Beh ~ P _x + Int

--> for some reason this model adjust better than the one before.

Finally, i run 2 regressions (with low explanatory power 20%-40%)
Int ~A_x + S _x + P _x
Beh ~ P _x + Int

Besides validation of TPB, I'm interested on extracting coefficients so that i can use them in a simulation (agent-based model) to recreate the behavior.

Please if someone has been working with this issues or has faced similar questions, any pointer will be very very useful!

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question is found in these...

https://psycnet.apa.org/doiLanding?doi=10.1037%2Fmet0000503

https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/abs/10.1177/00131644221105505